# How to get all lists on mailchimp API v3.0?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

At this moment one request returns 10 list objects. So how can I get all lists from API v3.0 or is it even possible? I don't see cursor_next or anything like that in the response I got from API.

I'm speaking about this endpoint: http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/lists-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this can be so hard, but I didn't found this information from MailChimp API v3.0. Instead some project in github adviced me what to do..

So the answer: **Pagination in API v3.0 is always done with count and offset**

Comment: Commenting on a four year old answer, but that makes me feel good about using MailChimp and this API.  It's mature and they are still around.  In addition to the always-use-paging rule, I will add another: ALWAYS specify which fields you want from the API!  If you rely on the defaults, you get EVERYTHING with every call and that makes your MailChimp API calls very slow.  You don't need MailChimp sending you down REST endpoint information with every call, so tell it not to. The more JSON they have to compose, the slower it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can send additional request that will return only lists count 
/3.0/lists?fields=total_items

and then use this value for next request 
/3.0/lists?count={totalItems}

Comment: If you're using \DrewM\MailChimp PHP wrapper 
`$lists = $mc->get('lists?count=100');`

Answer (score 1):

With MailChimp.Net.
This is an example with a while cycle and the offset value.

```
List<List> lists = new List<List>();
IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager(MailChimpApiKey);
bool moreAvailable = true;
int offset = 0;
while (moreAvailable)
{
    var membersRequest = manager.Lists.GetAllAsync( new ListRequest
    {
        FieldsToInclude = "fieldSample1",
        Limit = 10,
        Offset = offset
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var allList = membersRequest.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    foreach (List list in allList)
    {
        lists.Add(list);
    }
    if (allList.Count() >= 10)
        offset += 10;
    else
        moreAvailable = false;
}
```

Comment: Adding a Fields list to your ListRequest to specify which data you are interested in will improve your performance by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Bryan i added "FieldToInclude" as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for our help i have some customization work and its working with your help.

i have a code for helping developer who are facing same issue in future.

if ( ! empty( $mailchimp_api_key ) ) {

```
            $mailchimp_lists = get_transient( 'tbz_affwp_edd_mailchimp_lists' );

            if ( false === $mailchimp_lists ) {

                if ( ! class_exists( 'TbzAffWPMailChimp' ) ) {
                    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/api/MailChimp.php';
                }

                $Mailchimp = new TbzAffWPMailChimp( $mailchimp_api_key );
                $lists = $Mailchimp->get('lists?count=100');


                $lists_count = $lists['total_items'];

                if ( $lists_count >= 20 ) {

                    foreach ( $lists['lists'] as $list ) {
                        $mailchimp_lists[ $list ['id'] ] = $list['name'];
                    }

                    set_transient( 'tbz_affwp_edd_mailchimp_lists', $mailchimp_lists, 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );

                }

                return false;

            }

            return $mailchimp_lists;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, but just to be a bit more specific, I was using:

```
client.list.all(fields="lists.name,lists.id",)
```

This returned only 10 lists. To get all the lists available, this needs to be changed to either the number of lists you have or a higher number, in this case I randomly picked 100:

```
client.list.all(fields="lists.name,lists.id", count=100, offset=0)
```

Comment: I think picking the count randomly doesn't cut it. It brings random results.